# how to create xib subview at the center of tableview swift

Tags: swift, tableview, xib, subview, centralized

I have tableview and I created the custom xib uiview as "detailview" for it. I want to show this detailview at the center of scrolled area when tapped to tableview cell. I can show this view but cannot centralized it. when I set value to frame manually, subview will be at center (approximately) but when I tap the cell which is at the bottom, the subview is appearing at the top of page and also it is moving when i scroll the tableview.

Please help me to show this view at the center of the scrolled area and be fixed

Here is my codes;

Detail View :

```
class TopTenDetailView: UIView {

      var screenWidth:CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width*0.08
      var screenHeight :CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height*0.08

      class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
            return UINib(nibName: "TopTenDetail", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
      }

      override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            self.layer.cornerRadius=10

            let testFrame : CGRect = CGRectMake(screenWidth,screenHeight,320,480)
            self.frame = testFrame
            self.userInteractionEnabled=true
      }

      @IBAction func close(sender: UIButton) {
            self.hidden=true
      }
}
```

And TableViewController's method ;

```
      override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
             var detailView = TopTenDetailView.instanceFromNib
             self.view.addSubview(detailView())
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this is setup has many problems and i would be surprised if it actually ever works as intended.

A much better, simpler setup uses a `OverFullScreen` presentation style and it goes like this:

- Create a separate `UIViewController` for your detail view, let's call it `DetailViewController` use Interface Builder. Make sure to set the background color to CLEAR
- Wire up a segue from the "base" `UIViewController` that holds your `UITableView` to `DetailViewController` and give the segue a name. Let's call it 'detailSegue' , basically drag from one view controller to the other. Make sure that you are not dragging from the view but from the yellow icon at the top of the view controller. You are done in Interface Builder.

[image]
[image]

Ok, now for the code:

```
    // MARK : - UITableViewDelegate
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detailSegue", sender: self)
    }

    // MARK: - segues
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? UIViewController{
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen

        }
    }
```

The `OverFullScreen` presentation style uses a proper `UIViewController` modal segue but leaves the presenting `UIViewController` visible under the presented one.

You can then just layout whatever you want on `DetailViewController` using Interface Builder and autolayout without having to do hacky match calculations on the layout at runtime.

Hope it helps!

[image]
[image]